# Show hyperlinks automatically in moderator/10K flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderator-tools, flags, flag-queue

While going through the Super User mod flag queue this morning, I ran across a flag by Community:

[image]

As you can see, it shows the answer body in plain text.  I suspected that the answer was nothing more than a URL/hyperlink, so I clicked through to see, and it was:

[image]

**Feature request:** make the mod/10K flag queue preview match the answer automatically, i.e. without having to expand and send *another* request to the server, at least to the point where it shows hyperlinks.  We don't necessarily have to include blockquotes or code samples, but it would be helpful to see URLs.

<s>The other option is to show the post *exactly* as it has been formatted and *offer an expansion option,* similar to `/review`.</s> This feature is already in place, just click the small grey arrow to the left of the question title (*thanks* @RobertHarvey!).

What do you think?

Comment: The expansion option is that little grey triangle to the left of the answer body plain text.

Comment: @RobertHarvey is that what that is? `must click all them shiny buttonz` :P

Comment: Did you delete the answer?